# Switching cards in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am a little unclear as to the syntax to change cards in this example. I've tried making a ref to the panel, but that did not work. I'd like to switch card using the onButton function at bottom that is triggered by the submit button (just a button - not really using as a form in this example)

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',
    main: null,
    refs: [
    {
        ref: "main",
        selector: "mypanel"
    }
    ],
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            '#switch': {
                tap: this.onButton
            },
        })
    },
    launch: function() {
        this.main = Ext.create("Ext.Panel", {
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'card',
            xtype: 'mypanel',
            items: [
                {
                title: 'Home',
                iconCls: 'home',
                cls: 'home',
                html: 'home page',
            },
            {
                title: 'Contact',
                iconCls: 'user',
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                url: 'contact.php',
                layout: 'vbox',
                items: [
                   {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    title: 'Contact Us',
                    instructions: '(email address is optional)',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            label: 'Name'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'emailfield',
                            label: 'Email'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textareafield',
                            label: 'Message'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    itemId: 'switch',
                    id: 'switch',
                    text: 'Send',
                    ui: 'confirm',
                }
                ]
            }
            ]
        });

        this.main.setActiveItem(1);
    },
    onButton: function() {
            //? how do I switch from here
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `this.main.setActiveItem(1);` inside onButton() method?

If you want to toggle the cards by this "switch" button, you can just set a variable say `this.activeItemNo = 0;` inside "launch" method and use an if-else condition inside onButton method. Hope that helps.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Can you check console.log9this.main) inside onButton method?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a bug in ST dev preview 2.  The scope is not correctly passed to the onButton function. The expected way to switch is this.main.setActiveItem() which did not work for me because of this issue. The scope for now can be passed in the control method:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',
    main: null,
    refs: [
    {
        ref: "main",
        selector: "mypanel"
    }
    ],
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            '#switch': {
                tap: this.onButton
            },
        }, null, this)  //this is what is needed
    },
    launch: function() {
        this.main = Ext.create("Ext.Panel", {
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'card',
            xtype: 'mypanel',
            items: [
                {
                title: 'Home',
                iconCls: 'home',
                cls: 'home',
                html: 'home page',
            },
            {
                title: 'Contact',
                iconCls: 'user',
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                url: 'contact.php',
                layout: 'vbox',
                items: [
                   {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    title: 'Contact Us',
                    instructions: '(email address is optional)',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            label: 'Name'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'emailfield',
                            label: 'Email'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textareafield',
                            label: 'Message'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    itemId: 'switch',
                    id: 'switch',
                    text: 'Send',
                    ui: 'confirm',
                }
                ]
            }
            ]
        });

        this.main.setActiveItem(1);
    },
    onButton: function() {
        this.main.setActiveItem(0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Ext.getCmp('componentId').setActiveItem(1);`

You will of course need to assign an `id` to your main panel.